# Removing a string from a file using Perl

Tags: xml, string, perl

I have a file, and I need to remove a string whenever it appears in the file. The file contains the following text (example):

```
<RECORD><JOSE><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><JUAN><ISMAEL><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?></ISMAEL><NEWFILE><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?></NEWFILE></RECORD>
```

I need to remove this string every time it appears in the file.
String to be removed: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>`

I started using Perl this week, and I still have lots to learn.  This is the code I have so far but is not working.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = path('D:\Programs\PERL\perl_tests'); # /dir

my $file = $dir->child("tobeclean.txt"); # /file.txt

open(REMFILE,"<",$file) || die "couldn't open $file: $!\n";

while (<REMFILE>) {
     s{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>}{};
    print;
}

close(REMFILE);
```

Comment: Note that using bare file handles is discouraged.  Try `open my $remfile, '<', $file || die ...`

Comment: `path` is not a core function, nor is `child`. Are you using `Path::Tiny`? And why would you exclude that part of the code?

Comment: ... and if you are using `Path::Tiny` then there is no need for the builtin `open` as `Path::Tiny` has a number of methods for that purpose. (While there is nothing very wrong with using it, either.)

Answer (score 2):

The `?` is a meta-character.  What you have should work if you just escape it:

```
s{<\?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" \?>}{};
```

Unescaped, the `?` means that the previous atomic may or may not be present, so `ab?c` matches `abc` or `ac`.  Note that `.` is also a metacharacter, and should probably be escaped as well, but now you're down the rabbit hole.  It would probably be best to do:

```
my $k=quotemeta(q/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>/);
s{$k}{};
```

or similar to ensure that you get exactly what you want. Or search a fixed string using something like:

```
s{\Q<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>\E}{}'
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex you try is failing because `?` is a meta-character -- it has a special meaning in a regex pattern (it conditions the previous match), as explained already.  So you escape it and all is well.

But, what if that phrase comes spread over multiple lines in a file?  Then reading the file line-by-line can never find the whole thing in one regex.  Is it absolutely certain that the phrase is *always* entirely on one line?

To be safe, I'd suggest then to read the file into a string ("slurp" it). Then there may be linefeeds inside the phrase, if it is indeed over multiple lines, so use a more general pattern.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Path::Tiny;

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";

my $text = path($file)->slurp;

$text =~ s{<\?xml [^>]* >}{}xg;

say $text;
```

The pattern `[^>]*` picks up all characters that are not `>`, so everything up to the first `>`. But, this tag-like construct ("prolog", `<?xml...`) need be closed with `?>` so perhaps a more careful pattern could be

```
$text =~ s{<\?xml .*?(?= \?\s*>) \?\s*>}{}xg;
```

This uses a [lookahead assertion](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind), `(?= ...)`. I use `Path::Tiny` since the question clearly does (even though the `use` statement itself is left out!)

But really, is this file a proper format of any kind?  An XML?  (You are removing an XML document "prolog."  The shown string is invalid as XML in many ways but perhaps the actual data is different.)  If so, by all means better read it with a library.

Some good libraries to mention: `XML::LibXML`, `XML::Twig`, `Mojo::DOM`.

---

It has been clarified in a comment that the actual file contains valid XML, except for a "prolog" text (`<?xml...?>`) inside of it, what isn't valid. Then there are some possibilities:

- [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) is known for tolerating malformed HTML/XML.  A simple XML file that I make up for tests, with prolog-like snippets inserted around, is just parsed.  Those (prolog-like) segments are kept where they were.
- The otherwise strict `XML::LibXML` can also tolerate it with its [recover option](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/view/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod#recover),

  ```
  my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $text, recover => 2);
  ```

  Now the offending segments are dropped! I get back the good rest of the file.  This should not be relied on, being an outcome of an error in format, but perhaps it can be useful -- and the document *can be* parsed.

I don't know whether/how `XML::Twig` can manage broken XML.

Comment: The situation we are having is that we receive a big text file with thousands of XML records one after the other, and I found a way to parse the XML file, but that phrase is not allowing me to parse it because the phrase is only allowed to be present one time at the beginning of the document.  That's why I am trying to find a way to eliminate the phrase from the file but the file is good XML, besides that issue.

Comment: @IsmaelHernandez OK, thanks for clarification. If the file is good XML, other than for a prolog text inside, then libraries can still do it: `Mojo::DOM` (known for tolerating malformed HTML/XML) just parses (my simple made-up examples), keeping the loose `<?xml...?>` lines.  The `XML::LIbXML` can parse it, too, with the constructor `recover` option (`XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $text, recover => 2);`) -- dropping those loose `<?xml...?>` segments!  It gives me back just the good rest of the file.  Don't know that one can _rely_ on that... (Or, of course, clean by regex and then parse.)

Comment: Can find the recover option [in XML::LibXML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/view/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod#recover) document.

Comment: @IsmaelHernandez Added discussion/links of libraries to use for broken XML

Answer (score 2):

Perl makes it easy to iterate over a file and modify its contents.  You can do it from the command line.

```
perl -ipe's/\Q<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>//g' file.xml
```

This assumes that this string is always on a single line and doesn't span lines.